# kafka producer behavior with properties with retries and delivery.timeout.ms

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

As per the kafka documentation, when producer is set with retries and delivery.timeout.ms with default values Integer.MAX_VALUE and 12000ms then for any failed send of messages it should keep trying and the delivery attempt will be done for 12000ms post which it gives up sending records. Tried to run a kafka consumer connected to a single node(not a cluster) with a hope to see the retry behavior in the log and when the producer is sending messages (in a loop) i tried to shutdown kafka broker (Intention is to see if the failed records will be attempted again as the broker is down) but it says Connection refused (Is there a way this can be reproduced just for practical knowledge ?)

```
KafkaProducer<String,String> producer=new KafkaProducer<>(prop);
    ProducerRecord<String,String> rec=new ProducerRecord<String,String>("orange","123");
while(true) {
    producer.send(rec, new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata rm, Exception arg1) {
            System.out.println(rm.topic()+" "+rm.partition()+" "+rm.offset());
        }
        
    });
```

It displayed the log as below

```
02:29:37.981 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
02:29:38.032 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
02:29:38.059 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initiating connection to node 127.0.0.1:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) using address /127.0.0.1
02:29:39.060 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection with /127.0.0.1 disconnected
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.finishConnect(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.finishConnect(KafkaChannel.java:219)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:530)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:485)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:544)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:325)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:240)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
02:29:39.060 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node 0 disconnected.
```

Comment: probably `errors.retry.timeout` is also needed to be not 0, which is the default: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#sourceconnectorconfigs_errors.retry.timeout

Comment: @DmitriiBocharov- Thank you, not able to see any difference in behavior with the above setting.